# **Consider two non-parallel lines, MN and QR

Tags: geometry

**Consider two non-parallel lines, MN and QR

How many points in the plane MNQR are 2 cm from MN and 5 cm from QR

A 0

B 2

C 4

D Infinitely many**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: The points that are $2$ cm from $MN$ lie on two specific lines parallel to $MN$; what are those lines? Similarly, the points that are $5$ cm from $QR$ lie on two specific lines parallel to $QR$. The points that you want are those that are on one of the specific lines parallel to $MN$ **and** on one of the specific lines parallel to $QR$? How many such points of intersection are there? A rough sketch should settle the matter very quickly.

Further HINT: #

Comment: thanks brian m.scott but can you give me additional simple hint

Comment: @moamen: Not without just doing the problem for you. Let’s see if we can work through it a step at a time. Do you understand why the points $2$ cm from $MN$ lie on two lines parallel to $MN$? And if so, can you describe those two lines for me?

Comment: i dont under stand why the points 2 cm from MN lie on two lines parallel to M ? .......thanks for the help

Comment: @moamen: To keep things simple, let’s suppose that $MN$ is the $x$-axis. How far from the $x$-axis is the point $\langle 3,2\rangle$? How about the point $\langle 1,-2\rangle$?

Comment: the first one is 3 >>> the second is 1

Comment: are the answer is 4 ?

Comment: @moamen: You gave me the distances of the points from the $y$-axis, not from the $x$-axis: both are $2$ units from the $x$-axis. The points $2$ units from the $x$-axis lie on the lines $y=2$ and $y=-2$, parallel to the $x$-axis and two units away from it on either side. Similarly, the points $5$ cm from $QR$ lie on lines parallel to $QR$ and $5$ cm away on either side. The lines parallel to $QR$ are **not** parallel to $MN$, and vice versa, so the two lines parallel to $QR$ cross those parallel to $MN$, and you get a sort of # shape. And yes, you get $4$ points of intersection.

Comment: @Cameron: I have to admit that I had the same reaction when I thought of it!